# QtCreator не находит QODBC

Tags: qt, sql-server

При запуске программы с кодом:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","serviceCenter");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL SERVER};Server=192.168.1.106;Database=db_lab_serviceCenter;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
db.setUserName("Admin");
```

Вылетает с ошибкой

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
```

Я так понимаю это потому, что не стоит драйвер QODBC. Как его поставить? У меня стоит GNU/Linux Mint 13 и Qt версии 4.8.1

Comment: Вроде нашел как исправить, скомпилировал из сорцов драйвер odbc, но теперь другая проблема, при запуске такая вот ошибка

    /QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlodbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocHandle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Та ну зачем же собирать из исходников, когда за Вас уже всё собрано :)

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-odbc
```

Comment: я уже и так делал, не помогало, у меня просто Qt был установлен изначально с помощью онлайн инсталлера с сайта qt. Потом я поставил из репозиториев, но установился он все равно в папку, где стоял раньше, вобщем непонятная для меня штука случилось. Ну и когда я сделал

    sudo apt-get install libqt4-sql-odbc

либа не появилась и odbc все еще не работал, скачал исходники и собрал, появился файл libsqlodbc.so и я его закинул в QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/plugins/sqldrivers

Comment: db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","serviceCenter");

эта строка теперь заработала и драйвер odbc нашелся, но при добавлении вот этого

    db.setDatabaseName("Driver={SQL SERVER};Server=192.168.1.106;

выскакивает ошибка

    /media/win_d/ProgramFiles/projects/db_test-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK_______/db_test: symbol lookup error: /media/win_d/ProgramFiles/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlodbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocHandle

Comment: вру, эта ошибка выскакивает при вызове

    db.open();

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с такой интересной штукой, что из коробки в Qt'e лежит только sqlite, чтобы, допустим юзать ещё mysql, то нужно скачать этот самый mysql, именно сервер и взять от туда 2 динамические либы и закинуть в либы компилятора, если используете minGW  и вы под виндой, то в `(путь до qt'a)\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`, например `E:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin`